# Trouble accessing javascript property

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object called users inside a global object called streams. Each property of users is a username with the value of an array that stores other objects with info about each user. The project is supposed to be a small version of twitter. E.g:

```
var users = {};
users.bill = []
users.keith = [];

var someInfo = {};
someInfo.tweet = "Hello, I am a message";
someInfo.dateCreated = new Date();

users.keith.push(someInfo);
```

The above is in a separate .js file that is included in my index.html file. My index.html file also has a script section and that is where my problem lies. What I am attempting to do is retrieve the string from the tweet property, when a username is clicked on, using jQuery. Here is what I am trying.

```
var showTimeline = function (){
  var tweeter = $(this).text(); // get username from whichever name is clicked on
  console.log(tweeter);         // log name to console. e.g tweeter holds "keith"
  console.log(streams.users["keith"][0].message); // this works fine and extracts string as expected
  console.log(streams.users[tweeter][0].message); // program breaks here and says "tweeter is undefined", right after i logged it to the console and showed it holds the string "keith"

};
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kewigro/NkrK3/)

Comment: Show me a fiddle, but perhaps within ```users``` you didn't actually put a ```tweeter```

Comment: Hmmm...seems strange...so far to me it looks right on..

Comment: try : `var tweeter = $.trim($(this).text());`

Comment: Are u sure text contains "keith" and not "Keith" ?

Comment: @Cygwinnian Yes, you are correct that there is no tweeter inside users. I am just trying to use the variable tweeter as a placeholder for the string accessed by $(this).text(); Perhaps that is my problem?

Comment: I'll put up a fiddle, one moment

Comment: that returns streams.users[tweeter]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some invisible character(s) causing problems:

```
console.log(tweeter == 'douglascalhoun'); //false
```

This solves it:

```
var tweeter = $.trim($(this).text());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/26gwz/

Comment: or more elegant `$(this).text().trim()`

Comment: @MichaRadonov If you don't need to support IE8 or lower, or you want to create a shim for those browsers, yes.